# computing a column value using columns from two tables using trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

i want to create a trigger to compute the 'totalPrice' column in the following table here

```
 create table materialPriceAndStandard (
 id int identity(700,3),
 materialName nvarchar(100) not null default (0),
 unitPrice decimal(19,2) not null default (0),
 carbohydrate tinyint not null default (0),
 protein tinyint not null default (0),
 fat tinyint not null default (0),
 humidity tinyint not null default (0) ,
 minerals tinyint not null default (0),
 totalPrice decimal(19,2) default(0),
 constraint PK_id_materialPriceAndStandard primary key (id),
 constraint UQ_materialName_materialPriceAndStandard unique (materialName), 
 constraint CHECK_totlaMineralAmount check
 (carbohydrate + protein + fat + humidity + minerals  =100 ))
```

this is the trigger :

```
create trigger totalPrice 
ON materialPriceAndStandard
AFTER insert
as 
begin 
MaterialPriceAndStandard.totalPrice =
((select _weight from ingredients where
ingredients.material = 
materialPriceAndStandard.materialName * materialPriceAndStandard.unitPrice))
end
```

but i get the `syntax error` , how should i write the trigger to compute the value of '`totalPrice`' using the '`_weight`' column from `ingredients` table.

totalPrice = _weight * unitPrice.
 _weight belongs to ingredients table 
unitPrice belongs to materialPriceAndStandard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use proper T-SQL to handle your updating. Try something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER totalPrice 
ON materialPriceAndStandard
AFTER insert
AS BEGIN
    UPDATE mp
    SET mp.totalPrice = SUM(ing._weight) * mp.unitPrice
    FROM dbo.MaterialPriceAndStandard mp
    INNER JOIN Inserted i ON mp.ID = i.ID   -- make sure to update *only* those new rows!
    INNER JOIN dbo.Ingredients ing ON mp.ID = ing.ID
END
```

Also: your current code is very unclear (to me) on **how** to join the two tables, and **how to calculate** the new `TotalPrice` (the **price** is the sum of your **_weight**?!?!?!? Seems very very odd.....) - you might need to adapt this.

Also: I would probably not do this in a trigger - what happens if something gets **updated**? What happens in the `_weight` column of `dbo.Ingredients` changes? Wouldn't you have to update the `TotalPrice` column, too? Why don't you just calculate this `TotalPrice` when you really need it - e.g. in a view or on a reporting tool.

Comment: in case of somthing gets updated, can we use update trggier to handle that ? @marc_s

Comment: @AlirezaX: yes, if you really want to keep `TOtalPrice` up to date - then you'd also need an `UPDATE` (and possibly a `DELETE` trigger, if something is deleted from the `dbo.Ingredients` table)